# I want to take input from user by connecting buttons with lines on touch in Android

Tags: android

I have already created 10 buttons using XML and arranged them in circular order. Now i want to take input from user by connecting buttons with lines on touch similar to android pattern unlock.

I am new to Android. I have only created XML file.

xml code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".RoundBtn" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="222.08203dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="270.53426dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundshapebutton"
    android:text="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="162.08203dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="314.12678dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundshapebutton"
    android:text="2" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="87.917960dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="314.12678dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundshapebutton"
    android:text="3" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="27.917960dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="270.53423dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundshapebutton"
    android:text="4" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="200.00000dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundshapebutton"
    android:text="5" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="27.917960dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="129.46576dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundshapebutton"
    android:text="6" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="87.917960dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="85.873218dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundshapebutton"
    android:text="7" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="162.08203dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="85.873218dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundshapebutton"
    android:text="8" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="222.08203dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="129.46576dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundshapebutton"
    android:text="9" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="245.0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="199.99999dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundshapebutton"
    android:text="0" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show us what you did, by code.

Comment: I m new to android. I have only created xml file.